# Unable to configure nestjs/mongoose, initial database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am not sure I understand the nestjs/mongoose configuration.

I am not getting any results back and am assuming it is querying my admin database.

app.module.ts:

```
import { ConfigService } from './config/config.service';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { ConfigModule } from './config/config.module';
import { CaseAssetsModule } from './case-assets/case-assets.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    CaseAssetsModule,
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.getString('mongodb.uri'),
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    })
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my config setting:

```
mongodb.uri = mongodb://<<myuser>>:<<mypwd>>#@<<myserver>>:27017/admin
```

case-assets.module.ts:

```
import { AssetSchema } from './asset.schema';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { CaseAssetsController } from './case-assets.controller';
import { CaseAssetsService } from './case-assets.service';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Asset', schema: AssetSchema, collection: 'assets' }])],
  controllers: [CaseAssetsController],
  providers: [CaseAssetsService]
})
export class CaseAssetsModule {}
```

Where do I specify the database that I want to connect to? I specify admin because that is the database that I authenticate against.

Gina

Answer (score 17):

You've determined what database you want to connect to via the configuration given to the `MongooseModule.forRootAsync()` method. From there, anything used from `MongooseModule.forFeature()` uses the same configuration (i.e. the same database)

#### Edit with Solution

Okay, now I understand the problem. Looks like with mongo you can supply an `authSource` query parameter like so `mongodb://mongodb1.example.com:27317,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?authSource=authDB`. So long as you need auth for every model in your db, this kind of URI should handle it. You can pass this to the `MongooseModule.forRoot({})` or `MongooseModule.forRootAsync({})` configuration.

If you need this to be on a per model basis, however, I don't think the current `MongooseModule` can handle that.

#### Edit

Solution with two connections:

app.module.ts

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
 imports: [ConfigModule],
 connectionName: 'firstDB',
 useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
  uri: config.get('app.firstDB'),
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
 }),
 inject: [ConfigService],
}),
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
 imports: [ConfigModule],
 connectionName: 'secondDB',
 useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
  uri: config.get('app.secondDB'),
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
 }),
 inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

cats.module.ts

```
@Module({
 imports: [
  MongooseModule.forFeature(
   [
     {
      name: 'Cat',
      schema: CatSchema,
      collection: 'cats',
     },
    ],
   'firstDB',
  ),
 ],
})
export class CatsModule {}
```

dogs.module.ts

```
@Module({
 imports: [
  MongooseModule.forFeature(
   [
     {
      name: 'Dog',
      schema: DogSchema,
      collection: 'dogs',
     },
    ],
   'secondDB',
  ),
 ],
})
export class DogsModule {}
```

Comment: In MongooseModule.forRootAsync() where do I configure the database I want to connect to? In my connection string I specify the one I want to authenticate against. The authentication db and the db I want to connect to are different.

Comment: [There is an issue about it here](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/515) with an example. I'll add the example to my answer as well

Comment: I am not sure you are understanding me. I only want to connect to one database. I cannot connect to secondDB because I must auth against firstDB. In Mongo "admin" database is setup as my authentication DB.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean by `auth against firstDB`. Are you keeping authentication in one database and data in another database? It still sounds like two databases to me, but I'm not sure what kind of set up you are trying to work with anymore

Comment: Correct. In mongo you can chose where your user authentication is kept. I use admin. So cats and dogs are in seconddb. In your example does secondb know anything about firstdb? I cannot log in to seconddb because the authentication is admindb.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Thank you for such a detailed answer!